# XStream - Challenge adding attribute to child element

Tags: xstream, openjdk-12

I am having difficulty adding an attribute to a child element for writing an XML file. The challenge, for me at least, is that the POJO that the element is mapped to is associated with a parent element. I want the XML output to look like this:

```
<TXLife version="2.42.00" xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TXLifeRequest>
    <TransRefGUID>906D67C1-CC4D-11CF-91FB-444554540000</TransRefGUID>
    <TransType tc="1203"></TransType>
    <TransExeDate>2020-01-06</TransExeDate>
    <TransExeTime>09:30:00</TransExeTime>
    ...multiple other parent and child elements..
  </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

It's the **TransType** element in which I need to add the attribute (as shown above).

The POJOS:

```
@XStreamAlias("TXLife")
public class TXLife {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String version;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    final String xmlns = "http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2";

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("xmlns:xsi")
    final String xlink="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<TXLifeRequest> transListings = new ArrayList<TXLifeRequest>();

    public TXLife() {
        super();
    }
...getters and setters
```

```
@XStreamAlias("TXLifeRequest")
public class TXLifeRequest {

    @XStreamAlias("TransRefGUID")
    private String transRefGUID;

    @XStreamAlias("TransType")
    private String transType;

    @XStreamAlias("TransExeDate")
    private String transExeDate;

    @XStreamAlias("TransExeTime")
    private String transExeTime;

    public TXLifeRequest(String transRefGUID, String transType, String transExeDate, String transExeTime) {
        this.transRefGUID = transRefGUID;
        this.transType = transType;
        this.transExeDate = transExeDate;
        this.transExeTime = transExeTime;
    }
...getters and setters
```

Converter:

```
public class TransTypeAttributeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter hierarchicalStreamWriter, MarshallingContext marshallingContext) {
        TXLifeRequest txLifeRequest = (TXLifeRequest) o;
        hierarchicalStreamWriter.addAttribute("tc", "1203");
        hierarchicalStreamWriter.setValue("");
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader hierarchicalStreamReader, UnmarshallingContext unmarshallingContext) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(TXLifeRequest.class);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestXMLOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        TestXMLOutput testXMLOutput = new TestXMLOutput();

        TXLife txLife = new TXLife();
        txLife.setVersion("2.42.00");
        txLife.add(new TXLifeRequest("906D67C1-CC4D-11CF-91FB-444554540000", "",
                "2020-01-06", "09:30:00"));

        testXMLOutput.testConvertAndWriteXMLToFile(txLife);

    }

    public void testConvertAndWriteXMLToFile(TXLife txLife) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.processAnnotations(TXLife.class);
        xstream.alias("TXLife", TXLife.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(TXLifeRequest.class);
        xstream.alias("TXLifeRequest", TXLifeRequest.class);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("CITS_BoB/src/test/java/txlife.xml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException Occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        xstream.addImplicitCollection(TXLife.class, "transListings");
        //xstream.registerConverter(new TransTypeAttributeConverter());

        xstream.marshal(txLife, new PrettyPrintWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(bos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));


    }
}
```

I have found that running both the *xstream.addImplicitCollection(...)* and *xstream.registerConverter(...)* in the test class produces the following XML output:

```
<TXLife version="2.42.00" xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TXLifeRequest tc="1203"></TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

I am sure I have misunderstood, or missed altogether, how to properly use xstream to do this sort of task. In any examples I have found online the element to which the attribute is added is mapped to a class, whereas in my case the element I want to add the attribute to is itself in a class that is mapped to a "parent" element. I have gone through the [xstream](https://x-stream.github.io/) website but haven't found any example directly related to my goal here. JAXB is unfortunately not an option as I am using openjdk 12 which does not support that. I don't know if there is an XML document writer built into openjdk 12 (I am still new to that version). I guess what I can't figure out is how to somehow "associate" the specific child element in the TXLifeRequest POJO with the attribute I want added to it. Please excuse my incorrect use of code, for one, the string literals added in the *hierarchicalStreamWriter.addAttribute("tc", "1203");* statement in the **TransTypeAttributeConverter** I am sure are in the wrong context or place. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Sorry, I should also add that other options I have considered is to write POJOs for each element (which I realize is likely extreme and inefficient), or, to map the child element in the POJO to an inner class such that it in effect becomes it's own *parent* element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the java DOM parser as a solution, which allowed me to set the attribute directly on the element **TransType**. If by chance someone *does* know how to resolve this issue in XStream I would still be interested to know. Cheers.